# Need to display fabric js Object boundary Controls outside the canvas

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have created a canvas using the Fabric.js library and added boundary controls to the fabric.js objects. My goal is to display these fabric.js object boundary controls outside the canvas, allowing me to adjust the size of the elements from outside the canvas using these controls. However, I'm facing an issue where, when I drag the fabric.js elements, they become hidden inside the canvas instead of just showing the controls. How can I make sure that only the controls are displayed without the content inside the boundary box of the fabric.js elements?

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5OC7.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saiPy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.